Norm Inequality in Banach Algebra
Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a unital Banach Algebra and P,Q are two closed ideals of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $P\subseteq Q$. Then can we say $||x+P||\leq ||x+Q||\quad \forall x\in \mathcal{A}$ ?
I tried the following way
Since $P\subseteq Q$, so $\mathcal{A}/P$ is a sub-algebra of $\mathcal{A}/Q$. Thus the elements in $\mathcal{A}/P$ are in also $\mathcal{A}$. Then I am not getting any convenient way.

I am not familiar with this notation. What is the definition of $|x+P|$ when $P$ is a set?

If you are considering the quotient algebra the norm $|x+P|$ is the distance from $x$ to $P.$ So the inequality should be reversed.

If $P\subset Q$, then you have
$$
\|x+Q\|=\inf\{\|x+q\|:\ q\in Q\}\leq\inf\{\|x+p\|:\ p\in P\}=\|x+P\|. 
$$
